# Unable to build the sample project of intel cs webRTC for andriod

Tags: android

When I try to build "samples" project from the "CS_WebRTC_Client_SDK_Android.v4.2.1" on Windows, I get the following error message :

> Project with path ':src:sdk:conference' could not be found in project ':src:sample:conference'.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add intel conference SDK.

Use this Intel Webrtc Android sample
https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-client-android

Answer (score 0):

go to: openModulesSetting->> dependencies->> and add conference.aar to your modules ->>

selected other modules (like owt_base) and click on + button --> module dependency --> conference --> apply + ok

[image: image for description]